# Row missing in apt update output

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm checking the output of `sudo apt update`

```sh
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                             
Ign:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease                                                   
Hit:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                          
Hit:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release                    
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [283 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [355 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10,4 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [27,6 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [61,0 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.468 B]
Fetched 1.068 kB in 2s (507 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Why there is a gap at Row 8?

(Ubuntu 20.04.3. Version of apt is `apt/focal-updates,now 2.0.6 amd64`)

Content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder is

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list                         mongodb-org-4.2.list.save
clipgrab-team-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save                    mongodb-org-4.4.list
google-chrome.list                                          mongodb-org-4.4.list.save
google-chrome.list.distUpgrade                              skype-stable.list
google-chrome.list.save                                     skype-stable.list.save
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list                       vscode.list
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list.distUpgrade           vscode.list.save
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list.save                  yarn.list
libratbag-piper-ubuntu-piper-libratbag-git-focal.list       yarn.list.distUpgrade
libratbag-piper-ubuntu-piper-libratbag-git-focal.list.save  yarn.list.save
mongodb-org-4.2.list
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What do you think should be on row 8?

Comment: 20.04.3 , well I would expect not to have a gap, so 9 to be 8 instead.

Comment: If you have no errors, crashes or issues I would not even look at it.

Comment: The contents of `sources.list` might be helpful.

Comment: @AkbarkhonVariskhanov updated

Comment: There must be the following file on your system: `/etc/apt/sources.list`

This is where all APT tools fetch their sources from. Post its contents. `man 5 sources.list` for additional information about the file.